# How can in put an item under grid system (resized)

Tags: html, css

I'm just learning `html`, `css`, `boostrap`.
I want to put an item (`navbar`, a tag `div`, ...) under grid, but when I resized my browser,  it lays on the grid.

```css
#header {
  height: 40px;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#header>div {
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 44px;
}
#header div a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  height: 44px;
  color: #666;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: both;
}
#header div:hover a {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="header" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="contactinfo col-sm-8">  
      <p>
        <strong>Call :&nbsp;</strong>&nbsp;+84902xxxxxx &nbsp;|&nbsp; <strong>Email:&nbsp;</strong>&nbsp;xxx@gmail.com&nbsp;&nbsp;
      </p>          
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 signin">
      <a href="#" id="account">Sign in</a>                    
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-2 signup" >
      <a href="#" id="cart">Sign up</a>                    
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to do this. may it be helpful to you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>-->
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">
        <strong>Call :&nbsp; </strong>
        &nbsp;+84902xxxxxx &nbsp;|&nbsp; </a>
      </li>
        
      <li><a href="#"><strong>Email:&nbsp;</strong>&nbsp;xxx@gmail.com&nbsp;&nbsp</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
  
<div class="container">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```